# Using PHP Printer functions in PHP Desktop application

Tags: php, xampp, phpdesktop

#### In XAMPP environment

I develop and test my PHP code in XAMPP environment (local) and it success.

#### In PHP Desktop environment

I already copied the `php_printer.dll` into the ext folder and include this line `extension=php_printer.dll` in the `php.ini` file.

I also moved my folder from htdocs (XAMPP environment) to the www folder (PHP Desktop environment) but when I run the `phpdesktop-chrome.exe` it shows `...undefined function printer_list()...` so I knew that it cannot recognize the library.

#### My question

How do I configure PHP Desktop to recognize the php_printer.dll as similar to my XAMPP behavior?

## Update 1

php_printer.dll failed to load. By the way how do I identify my php_printer.dll  version whether it match PHP Desktop or not? Thank you.
[image]

## Update 2

Okay I have the version as below:
**PHP Desktop**: `phpdesktop-chrome-57.0-rc-php-7.1.3`
**php_printer.dll:** `php_printer-php5.6.30`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP extensions are often intended for specific PHP versions (eg. 5.12.xx and Thread-safe or non-thread-safe). If your extension doesn't match specific php version it won't work. In such case you should see a startup error if you enable it in php.ini.

For detecting problems during PHP startup see:

1. https://github.com/cztomczak/phpdesktop/wiki/Knowledge-Base#problem-running-php-script
2. https://github.com/cztomczak/phpdesktop/wiki/Knowledge-Base#error-500-internal-server-error-cgi-program-sent-malformed-or-too-big-16384-bytes-http-headers

**Update**

Your extension is for php 5.6.30, so you should download that specific php version, see: https://github.com/cztomczak/phpdesktop/wiki/Knowledge-Base#php-interpreter--extensions

Try non-thread-safe version first and then thread-safe version.

Comment: Woah the legendary PHPD founder replied!

Comment: @4LeaveCover :) Updated my answer.

Comment: @CzarekTomczak How can I update php version in phpdesktop?

Comment: @Lucky See https://github.com/cztomczak/phpdesktop/wiki/Knowledge-Base#php-interpreter--extensions

Comment: @CzarekTomczak Already tried but connection failure occurs. I downloaded VC14 x86 Non Thread Safe as specified but it failed to start with the new and old php.ini file. Please guide how can I bind phpmyadmin to this setup.

Comment: Is si4win same as phpdesktop? simple invoices